# Calculating the modulation based on the coordinates in the constellation diagram

Tags: signal-analysis

A constellation diagram has points at the following coordinates: `(2,2)`, `(2,-2)`, `(-2,2)`, `(0,-2)`. What is the modulation used by the modem?

This is literally never explained in my textbook and I can't do it by logic, since I have NO clue what a constellation diagram is.

Comment: Are you sure that the last coordinate isn't `(-2,-2)`?

Comment: My textbook says (0,-2). I wouldn't know if it is a mistake.

Comment: If you have no clue what a constellation diagram is why don't you first check out the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constellation_diagram) and then come back with a more concrete question?